# Unknown "SP2-0552: Bind variable "NEW" not declared" message on trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, toad

I have this trigger in one of my scripts:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MS_DB.DB_TR_IncrementTrialNumber BEFORE INSERT 
ON MS_DB.DB_SUMMARY FOR EACH ROW

begin
    UPDATE MS_DB.DB_Summary SET MS_DB.DB_Summary.TimesGenerated =
        (Select COALESCE(MAX(TimesGenerated),0)+1 
         From MS_DB.DB_Summary
         Where MS_DB.DB_Summary.StepID = :NEW.StepID And 
         MS_DB.DB_Summary.ValidationID = :NEW.ValidationID AND  
         MS_DB.DB_Summary.SummaryDate = :NEW.SummaryDate);
    where MS_DB.DB_Summary.ID = :NEW.ID;
end;
/
```

I use TOAD for executing the the script.
When I use 'Execute as Script' button it works fine.
But when I run it in SQLPlus window I get this line :

```
SP2-0552: Bind variable "NEW" not declared
```

Any ideas why I am getting this?
Thanks

Comment: `:NEW` is a placeholder. you want just `NEW` (no `:`), which refers to the new row -- which is exactly what the error tells you "bind variable NEW not declared".

Comment: Is it emulating the default SQL\*Plus blank line behaviour, perhaps? In other words, is it seeing the block as separate from the `create` - does it work if you remove the blank line before the `begin`?

Comment: It was your answer Alex Poole. It is fixed.Thanks

Comment: What is a "SQLPlus window"? Is this a TOAD thing or did you mean actual Oracle SQL*Plus? I can create triggers with blank lines in SQL*Plus without needing to `set sqlblanklines`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default SQL*Plus treats a blank line as the end of a statement. The first line, the `create`, is never executed. The rest is executed as an anonymous block, and as it is no longer part of a trigger statement the `NEW` isn't recognised.

You can either remove the blank line before the `begin`, or do [`set sqlblanklines on`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG102) before you start.

Comment: In fact, there was another error. The semicolon before where need to be removed.

Comment: Yes, didn't look at what the trigger was actually doing, but you're right. Aren't you going to get a mutating table error the way you've coded it? You're querying and updating (!) the same table the trigger is against.